# What is the meaning of location?

Tags: computing

I tried going on an English dictionary in google called dictionary.com to find the definition of Location. I really do not understand the definition of the word location. If someone could explain the definition of location in computer memory that would help. Tell me which English dictionary in google you used to help me find the meaning of the word location?

Comment: See [definition 1.3](https://en.oxforddictionaries.com/definition/location)

Comment: I swear I saw this identical question a day or two ago. Moreover, here is the actual definition of sense 5 of *location* from [dictionary.com](https://www.dictionary.com/browse/location): "5 Computers . any position on a register or memory device capable of storing one machine word." What is it about this definition that you don't understand? Without understanding *why* this is unclear, any answer given will likely not provide anything more meaningful.

Answer (score 3):

*Location*, in most contexts (including the context of computer memory) refers to the **place that can be described with some system of notation**. So for example, my variable in computer memory could have *location* 0x7fff9575c05e, which distinguishes where the information for my variable is stored.

Comment: To be precise, it gives it a name, which is called (and works like) a place. The actual physical location is another matter, given the way memories work

Comment: @Jerome Wei What English dictionary in google did you use to find the definition of location?

Comment: @ALLANKIZA please don't edit someone's answer simply because you don't think it provides what you asked for. Though it lacks an external reference to support it (perhaps because Jerome is new to our site and didn't realise authoritative references are expected), the information this answer provides is worthwhile, and I've upvoted it. If your focus is purely on a dictionary entry, see my answer. :-)

Answer (score 0):

[This site](https://www.onelook.com/?w=location&ls=a) is useful to enter a word and find a list of all the online dictionaries that have an entry for that word. From that list, I found that Oxford Living Dictionaries has a definition that includes its application in computer terminology, and offers a number of examples:

> **[location](https://en.oxforddictionaries.com/definition/us/location)**
>   noun
>
> 1.3 A position or address in computer memory.
>
> - *‘The first set of control input parameters is stored in a memory location.’*
> - *‘To get started, suppose we are trying to debug a specific instruction at an address location in the kernel.’*
> - *‘The location of the data packet in memory is then sent to a FIFO entity associated with the appropriate output link.’*
> - *‘The RAM has a first location for storing the data signal and a second location for storing the initialization status indicator.’*

In other words, while *location* retains its sense of "a particular place or position", in digital storage it doesn't make sense to refer to a specific *physical* location within (say) memory, but a key concept is the **address** allocated to the data.